# How to read a flat file and load it into 2 different SQL tables(different table structure) using SSIS 2019

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a flat file which doesn't have the header record. The data except the trailing record is like a fixed width flat file with no delimiters.

Data in flat file looks like:
TOM ROLLS
DAVECHILLS
TOTAL2XYZ

Fixed Width data(first 2 lines as shown in the above flat file data)
ColumnName  Start position End position
Name        1               4
Last_name   5               9

I want to load the data(till trailing record) in data_table and the trailing record(starting with Total) in another table. The data in the total table should look like

c1  c2
2   XYZ

For the data table, I am currently using "fixed width" and dividing the data into different column and it is working fine. Can you please help to load this last trailing record in a different table(Total table as discussed above)

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough data for me to test because I can find several methods to load one row and accomplish what you are asking but those methods not necessarily work with multiple rows depending on the structure of you source data.

On the surface it appears that you simply need to make another flat file connection and define the starting and end position to extract only the data for the second table.